# Utilize two objects for a single topojson merge. Multiple datum in d3.select("svg")

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am attempting to merge the state of Oklahoma with a single county in Texas.

I have two variables, one which uses the state id for the entire state of Oklahoma, and a second which contains the county id for the county in Texas. How do I combine a state.geometries.filter and a county.geometries.filter? There are actually a number of counties in Texas that will be merged but this one was chosen at random for the sake of example.

My code, which only returns the bottom most datum, is as follows:

```
.county-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.7px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.state.southcentral {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: #fff;
}

<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = d3.geoPath();

var southcentral = {
  "40": 1
};

var southcentral_c = {
  "48043": 1
};

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));

     //multiple datum, only shows the bottom most one. Need to combine into one merge but they use different objects in the JSON.

     svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in southcentral; })))
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in southcentral_c; })))
      .attr("class", "state southcentral")
      .attr("d", path);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haven't tested it but the api for `merge` states that it accepts an array of multipolygon objects. So i think you can just concat the 2 filtered objects and pass in the us topology.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in southcentral; })
arr[1] = us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in southcentral_c; })

svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, arr))
      .attr("class", "state southcentral")
      .attr("d", path);
```

EDIT::

```
var arr = [];
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr,us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in southcentral; }))
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr,us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in southcentral_c; }))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. If I call a value from the array .datum(topojson.merge(us, arr[1])) then it returns the county, but it doesn't work if I just use arr. Could some function that uses arr[i] work?

Comment: Oh, i think it's cause i neglected the fact that `filter` returns an array. As a test try adding `[0]` to the end of the 2 filtering statements, so that `arr` contains 2 objects, instead of 2 arrays. It makes sense that it works when you try `arr[1]`, because with my incorrect answer, `arr[1]` returns an array with a single object.

Comment: It worked! I'm not entirely sure I understand what that changed. Thank you though!

Comment: See my goal was for arr to contain 2 multipolygon objects. like `arr[obj,obj]`. The `filter` function returns an array, even if you only find 1 object, so both of your filtering functions returned `arr[obj]`. When I put both of those results into `arr`, we got `arr[arr[obj],arr[obj]]` instead of `arr[obj,obj]`. hope that makes sense, just a silly oversight by me.

Comment: As I'm progressing through this I'm realizing that by adding the `[0]` to the end of each filtering statement it only makes the first value in each array appear, in some cases I will have as many as 50 values in the array. It works for the example I posted because I only included 1 state and 1 county. Am I overlooking the fix here?

Comment: The `[0]` fix was just a testing case. The actual fix is to ensure `arr` is a "flat" array, that is, it only contains multipolygon objects, and not arrays. Check my edit.

Comment: My apologies, but I'm not 100% following. Wouldn't that mean that since the `filter` returns an array, and that I have an array of `ids` that in its current form it will never be "flat"? Currently I have `arr[arr[obj],arr[obj]]` and I'm not entirely sure how that could be flattened with the fact that each `arr[i]` will have it's own array of data.

Comment: Stackoverflow did not save my edit, try checking my edited answer. `push.apply` will "flatten" your filtered data when it gets pushed to `arr`.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for all your help, Eric. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MatthewSnell if Eric answered the question then you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it, so that Eric can get some points.